# subcategory will not show as parent category

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to get my subcategory based on the category
here is my code

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Category</label>
    <select id="categoryList" class="form-control" name="category_id" required>
       <?php
  $categories = $this->crud_model->get_categories()->result_array();
  foreach ($categories as $key => $category):?>
            <option value="<?php echo $category['slug']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></option>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>

    <label>Subcategory</label>
    <select id="subcategoryList" class="form-control" name="subcategory_id" required disabled>
      <?php
      $sub_categories = $this->crud_model->get_sub_categories($category['id']);
      foreach ($sub_categories as $sub_category): ?>
    <option id="sub_category-<?php echo $sub_category['id'];?>" name="sub_category"  class="parent-<?php $selected_category_id == $sub_category['id'] ?> subcategory" value="<?php echo $sub_category['slug']; ?>"><?php echo $sub_category['name']; ?></option> 
    <?php  endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```

the jquery

```
$('#categoryList').on('change', function () {
    $("#subcategoryList").attr('disabled', false); //enable subcategory select
    $("#subcategoryList").val("");
    $(".subcategory").attr('disabled', true); //disable all category option
    $(".subcategory").hide(); //hide all subcategory option
    $(".parent-" + $(this).val()).attr('disabled', false); //enable subcategory of selected category/parent
    $(".parent-" + $(this).val()).show(); 
});
```

but it will only show the last category's subcategories
how can I fix this?

alternatively i was using this code before

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Category</label>
        <select id="categoryList" class="form-control" name="category_id" required>
           <?php
      $categories = $this->crud_model->get_categories()->result_array();
      foreach ($categories as $key => $category):?>
                <option value="<?php echo $category['slug']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></option>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>

        <label>Subcategory</label>
        <select id="subcategoryList" class="form-control" name="subcategory_id" required disabled>
          <?php
          $sub_categories = $this->crud_model->get_sub_categories($category['id']);
          foreach ($sub_categories as $sub_category): ?>
        <option id="sub_category-<?php echo $sub_category['id'];?>" name="sub_category"  class="parent-<?php $selected_category_id == $sub_category['id'] ?> subcategory" value="<?php echo $sub_category['slug']; ?>"><?php echo $sub_category['name']; ?></option> 
        <?php  endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        
    </div>
```

jquery

```
$(function () {
    $("select.dependent").each(function (i, sel) {
        var original = $(this).clone(),
            dependent = $("<select></select>").attr({
                name: this.name
            }).insertAfter(this)
            this.name = "categories_" + this.name

            $("optgroup", this).replaceWith(function () {
                return "<option>" + this.label + "</option>"
            })
            $("option:first",this).prop("selected",true)
            $(this).removeAttr("multiple").on("change", function () {
                var cat = $(this).val()
                dependent.html(original.children("[label='" + cat + "']").html())
            }).change()
            console.log(this)
    })
    
})
```

but since I need 2 selects one individually for sub-categories that I can put an onchange="filter(this)" for it that show the result only based on the subcategory I've changed my code to first part
so if there is a way that I can do that in the second part that can fix my problem too

Comment: Can you please provide a working demo

Comment: I dont see any `subcategory` or `parent-<val>` class in html

Comment: i have corrected the code

Comment: You cannot do these things this way. What I could understand is that you have a main parent category and a sub category. You want to change/populate the sub categories data based on selected main category right? And from this code it looks like you are trying to do something with jQuery but let me tell you that first you will have to fix that php code.

Comment: `<?php $selected_category_id == $sub_category['id'] ?>`  this doesn't print anything ? if you inspect browser console you will see all class has `parent- subcategory` ?

Comment: You need to change the way you are making your sub categories dropdown. Do it like this. Run categories for each again and then for every category make the subcategory <select> block with id as parent-<category ID>. So after this you will have multiple subcategories for every main category. Keep them hidden all the time and only selected parent category id will be shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your originally posted code let's review what it's doing:

```
<label>Subcategory</label>
    <select id="subcategoryList" class="form-control" name="subcategory_id" required disabled>
      <?php
      $sub_categories = $this->crud_model->get_sub_categories($category['id']);
      foreach ($sub_categories as $sub_category): ?>
    <option id="sub_category-<?php echo $sub_category['id'];?>" name="sub_category"  class="parent-<?php $selected_category_id == $sub_category['id'] ?> subcategory" value="<?php echo $sub_category['slug']; ?>"><?php echo $sub_category['name']; ?></option> 
    <?php  endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```

Since PHP is processed on the server side and no other AJAX calls are in play here the line `$sub_categories = $this->crud_model->get_sub_categories($category['id']);` will only ever produce the sub-categories to the last category in the block above. This is the root of your problem, you needed to iterate over the categories again to get the sub-categories for each category.

I have altered your code combining the two together to show what changes were made to `foreach` over the categories, `jQuery.hide()` the subcategory selects, and then `jQuery.show()` only the one selected when a `category` is selected.

```
<script>
  $('#categoryList').on('change', function () {
    var catId = $(this).val();

    // This will go through each item on the page with class subcategory
    $('.subcategory-group').each(function(key, val) {
      $(val).hide();
      $(val).find('select').attr('disabled', true);
    });

    // Find the correct subcategory using the category id, not make it disabled, set the value to nothing
    $("#subcategory-" + catId).show();
    $("#subcategoryList-" + catId).attr('disabled', false).val("").show();
  });
</script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="categoryList">Category</label>
  <select id="categoryList" class="form-control" name="category_id" required>
      <?php
      $categories = $this->crud_model->get_categories()->result_array();
      foreach ($categories as $key => $category):?>
        <option value="<?php echo $category['slug']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>

  <?php
  // Iterate over the categories again
  foreach($categories as $category):
  ?>
      <div id="subcategory-<?php echo $category['slug']; ?>" class="subcategory-group">
        <!-- Set the label correctly for ADA compliance, showing the name of the category so you can see it working -->
        <label for="subcategoryList-<?php echo $category['slug']?>" class="subcategory-label">Subcategory - <?php echo $category['name']; ?></label>
        <!-- Set the id to something unique using the category id, set a class named subcategory, keep the name so your PHP form can handle it -->
        <select id="subcategoryList-<?php echo $category['slug']?>" class="form-control" name="subcategory_id" required disabled>
          <?php
          // Keeping the code you had which is correct
          $sub_categories = $this->crud_model->get_sub_categories($category['id']);
          foreach ($sub_categories as $sub_category): ?>
            <option id="sub_category-<?php echo $sub_category['id']; ?>" name="sub_category"
                    class="categories custom-select"
                    value="<?php echo $sub_category['slug']; ?>"><?php echo $sub_category['name']; ?></option>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
      </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

The changes include looping over the categories again to get all the subcategories that's why you only have the last one.

The next thing was to use the category id to be unique in the subcategory groups.

Following by using the proper `for` attribute on the labels for ADA compliance.

Adding a `subcategory` class on the `<select>` tags so that you can find (and hide) all the ones initially and then show only the one that they picked.

EDIT: Changed to use the `$category['slug']` instead of `$category['id']` per specifications not listed in original request

Comment: I have implemented your code and see what happens that's my issue I have mentioned the demo in comment above

Comment: This issue is one that's common in the beginning working through loops from the database and bringing it to the presentation layer. It should cover what you are looking for at least from what I can see.

Comment: I did and the code you provided showed me the problem. Let me highlight the issue in my answer for posterity

Comment: still the same with the code you've provided see the demo

Comment: Instead of going through the Javascript error in the code you ask me to look at the demo?

Comment: Updated to remove whatever you were doing with parent. It appears that's where the error was coming from.

Comment: still the same i don't know what is causing the problem also updated my post

Comment: Updated to `$(".subcategory").each(...)` instead of the way I was doing it. I had a logic error

Comment: same again - any option in the second way I've posted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230080/discussion-between-catchmeifucan-and-hppycoder).